# How to use djangorestframworkjwt properly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement [django-rest-frameworkjwt](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt) but I'm facing one problem as showing in image below. I'm trying to follow django-restframeworkjwt documentations and [rest-auth documentation.](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#jwt-support-optional) [image]

Here I'm using custom user model

```
from .managers import CustomUserManager


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(_("Username"), max_length=50, unique=True)
    ..........

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', ]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.userprofile.first_name + " " + self.userprofile.last_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.userprofile.first_name


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name=_("User"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(_("First name"), max_length=50)
   ....................
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api-token-refresh/', refresh_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api-token-verify/', verify_jwt_token),
    path('api/v1/', include('apps.urls.v_1')),
]
```

and settings.py

```
# Application definition

TENANT_MODEL = "tenant.Client"

SHARED_APPS = [
    "tenant_schemas",
    "apps.tenant"
]

TENANT_APPS = [
.........
    "rest_framework",
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    "apps.users",
]

INSTALLED_APPS = SHARED_APPS + TENANT_APPS


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}
REST_USE_JWT = True
```

Am I doing somethings wrongs. Here I'm using three packages djangorestframeworks, rest-auth, djangorestframworkjwt.
I'm using

```
rest-auth and django restframworkjwt
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are missing one or possible two things,

1. `rest-auth` urls:  `url('^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls'))`
2. set your custom user in the settings: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'` (I can't see your whole settings, you might have this point cover)

Comment: already available in other urls file and, stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post too many code